# need clarification on this code I am writing to find the mode of an array

Tags: javascript

For some reason I have just not been able to understand what is going on in this code

```
function mode(arr){
  var modecount = {}; // creating an object to add number and its mode
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ //iterating through array
    if(!modecount[arr[i]]){ /*This part I don't understand what do these two lines mean?
    I interpret it as if the current number in the array doesn't equal a number already
    in the modecount object then it equals 0 */
      modecount[arr[i]] = 0;
    }
    modecount[arr[i]] += 1; /* also what is happening here it is adding 1 to the value
    of modecount but why does it not add 1 to unique numbers and how does the code know
    to add 1 if it finds duplicates? */
    }
  return modecount;
}
mode([3,4,3,43,4,34,34,3,3,3,3,3]);
```

It seems like Ive been staring at this code for several hours and just cant get it. Somebody please explain this to me like I am a 3 year old.

Comment: The test `if(!modecount[arr[i]]){ ` would be much better as `if (!modecount.hasOwnProperty(arr[i]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the high level explanation:

It's taking a list of numbers, and it's counting the number of times each number appears in that list.

Now, here are the inline explanations:

```
function mode(arr){

  // Initialize an object literal 
  var modecount = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // If the value of arr[i] does NOT exist in the object modecount
    if (!modecount[arr[i]]) { 

      // Set the count of arr[i] to zero
      // Why? Because it if doesn't exist
      // then doing modecount[arr[i]] += 1 will throw an error
      // because modecount[arr[i]] will be undefined. 
      modecount[arr[i]] = 0;
    }

    // We increase the count of arr[i] in modecount by 1.
    // You asked about duplicates. 
    // It handles duplicates fine because modecount 
    // acts as a hash map (every key is unique). 
    // Doing modecount[5] over and over will 
    // give you the same value associated with 5.
    modecount[arr[i]] += 1;
    }

  return modecount;
}
// Call the function with our array
mode([3,4,3,43,4,34,34,3,3,3,3,3]);
```

I think this logic, while correct, can be improved. The assignment to 0 that follows the first IF statement reduces clarity. Why set to zero if it doesn't exist? It only makes sense after I read the next few lines.

Here's how I would rewrite it:

```
function mode(arr) {
    var modeCount = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Save the value so we don't have to do arr[i] every time
        var currMode = arr[i];
        // If it exists
        if (modeCount[currMode]) {
            // Increment by 1
            modeCount[currMode]++;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, it's the first one
            modeCount[currMode] = 1;
        }
    }

    return modeCount;
}

console.log(mode([3, 4, 3, 43, 4, 34, 34, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]))
```

Comment: Strictly, `if (!modecount[arr[i]])` means "if the expression returns a falsey value". The OP can get away with it here, but a more explicit test would use *hasOwnProperty*. Storing *arr.length* may more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically counting the number of time a particular value in the passed array exists but with base value of 0 for first occurence of the value to initialize the property at that value.

Even though `modecount` is specified as an object, the way one can access properties of an object in a variable manner is by using bracket notation.  So the output of

```
mode([3,4,3,43,4,34,34,3,3,3,3,3]);
```

Would be:

```
{ 3: 7, 4: 2, 43: 1, 34: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume the first part is just shorthand to check if `modecount[arr[i]]` has been initialized/defined yet. If it returns a "falsey" value it is either not initialized (accessing `modecount[arr[i]]` returns `undefined`) or has a 0 value - the latter is not possible because the next line *always* immediately increments the 0 to 1.

Note you could replace this check with `if(typeof(modecount[arr[i]]) === "undefined")` for equivalent and more explicit behavior.

As for the overall operation of the function, consider the following pesudocode:

```
var modecount = {}

foreach element in array:
    if modecount[element.value] is not defined:
        modecount[element.value] = 0

    modecount[element.value]++
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. I reworded a couple variables because i felt it read a bit nicer.

```
function mode(arr){

  // create an index for our counter
  var index = {};

  // a normal for-loop to iterate through the passed in numbers
  for(var i=0, num; i<arr.length; i++){

    // each time the foor loop runs, set num to arr[i]
    num = arr[i];

    // if no valid counter was found...
    if(!index[num]){

      // then create a new counter; initialize to 0
      index[num] = 0;
    }

    // add 1 to the counter
    index[num] += 1;
  }

  // return the counters
  return index;
}

mode([3,4,3,43,4,34,34,3,3,3,3,3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function loops through the passed array, storing each incident number as a number:count pair on the modecount object. So as your function works, the modecount object is going to look like this:

```
{}
{ 3: 1 }
{ 3: 1, 4: 1 }
{ 3: 2, 4: 1 }
{ 3: 2, 4: 1, 43: 1 }
{ 3: 2, 4: 2, 43: 1 }
and so on...
```